# nginx redirecting to a new domain

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a few old domains that I am redirecting to a new domain (consolidating), anyway the old and new ones had a predictable structure for everything, so I did this...

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name .oldomain.com;
        return 301 http://newdomain.com/foo$request_uri?;
}
```

and this takes care of all of my redirects, except for if someone types the bare address in. In that case they get a 404 because it redirects to /foo/ and there is nothing there.

Is there a way to take care of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the default case into a `location /` block, then you can explicitly specify edge cases. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .oldomain.com;

    location / {
        return 301 http://newdomain.com/foo$request_uri;
    }
    location = / {
        return 301 http://newdomain.com/my/default/path.html;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details of `location` syntax and processing order.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I don't get the significance of the = sign and how that is pointing to a different location than just /

Comment: @deltaskelta added a reference to the documentation that should help.